# Django compress error: Invalid input of type: 'CacheKey'

Tags: python, django, ansible, django-compressor

We suddenly started getting this issue when compressing django static files on production servers. Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.x, Django 1.11. I am using an ansible-playbook to deploy.

The error is as follows:

`CommandError: An error occurred during rendering /chalktalk/app/chalktalk-react-40/chalktalk-react-40/chalktalk/apps/exams/templates/exams/section-edit.html: Invalid input of type: 'CacheKey'. Convert to a byte, string or number first.`

It doesn't seem to be an issue in one of the static files but a general issue. Every time we run it, we get a different file.

I was looking for any clues on google and nothing shows up with the same error.

Comment: Good timing! I am damn sure all using django-redis must have been broken their prod environments with the unexpected backward incompatible changes.

Comment: @Babu It only broke our CI.  Its not really the fault of redis-py, after all it was a _major_ version bump so compatibility is explicitly not expected.  django-redis should have been restricting what versions they allow, but even that is not an "incompatible change" on their part, just a bug in their setup.py.

Comment: Yeah, not blaming anyone here :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is due to an change in the `redis` library between v2 and v3.  Try pinning your `redis` version to `2.10.6` from August 17, 2017, the last `redis` version before the change.

```
pip install redis==2.10.6
# and/or
echo redis==2.10.6 >> requirements.txt
```

I am not sure what package you are using which may be requiring redis as a dependency, or if you are using it yourself.  In either case its the same process.

In my case this shows up through the `django-redis` package, which requires the underlying `redis` package.  `Django-redis` doesn't restrict the **maximum** version, so it happily upgrades past a major version bump, which you can't really do since thats where you expect the API to change!

The exact code (in my case), in master at [django-redis](https://github.com/niwinz/django-redis/blob/master/setup.py#L25):

```
install_requires = [
    "redis>=2.10.0",
]
```

But it should really be this

```
install_requires = [
    "redis>=2.10.0, <3",
]
```

Edit: I found the [bug report in django-redis (#342) about this](https://github.com/niwinz/django-redis/issues/342) just now, but this SO question came up first in google when I was looking into it.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I actually have in my requirements.txt `django-redis-cache==1.6.5 celery[redis]==3.1.23 asgi-redis==1.4.3 channels-redis==2.1.0`. But I found out that the ansible playbook is installing debian packages and one of them is `redis-tools` and that has no version requirement so it is installing `3.0.6`

Comment: Do I pin the redis version by just adding it to the requirements.txt file `redis==2.10.6` before the django-redis-cache and other redis dependent packages?

Comment: I just added redis==2.10.6 in my requirements.txt and it worked :)

Comment: @nmusleh Yes, thats all you should need if you are installing via `pip install -r requirements.txt` since it will force that version.  If you are using other package managers, or if installing/upgrading manually with `--upgrade` then it will upgrade dependencies unless you tell it not to with `--no-deps`.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing redis-py below version 3

Comment: This is look like a comment please delete it and paste your proper answer and read [How to Write good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Technically he is correct, though without providing any supporting docs and so on there would be no way to evaluate it.